# Excel power query refresh locks up source file. Complete Excel shutdown required to unlock

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

The client file has a power query to a source file. Source file lives on a server drive. If the query is refreshed in the client file, and the source file is opened afterwards, the latter cannot be saved anymore, unless all (and I mean: all, not just the client file) of Excel files are closed on the client computer. If client file is closed before opening the source file, then all is OK.

This is annoying in the current workflow and leads to loss of time and productivity. Ideally, the client file has to remain open all day long, and allow for source file to be modified and saved several times a day without hassle.

Query in client file has been deleted and recreated several times to no avail, and shows up as a query, and not a connexion.

Any known issues or workarounds? I have been browsing by and large, and couldn't find a proper solution.

Regards,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this an inappropriate use of Excel - it is not designed for shared concurrent access (by Power Query or other means).

I would look to move the data in the source file to any of these options or similar:

1. Excel file in a SharePoint Document library
2. SharePoint or Microsoft 365 List

They both have easy import/upload options - would take 5-10 minutes to set up (once you have found/set up the home Team/Group). You would need to rebuild the early steps in you Power Query but that is also a 5-10 minute job.

There are many other options for sharing data (vs file share direct access to Excel), e.g. SQL database, other cloud platforms.  But the 2 options above are usually no extra cost and certainly the quickest and easiest to migrate to.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was considering downvoting though. We have a heavy network of Excel files, with 10s of formula and macro-heavy tabs cross referrenced between many workbooks. The system was built upon many small improvements to automate tasks; be it appropriate or not isn't really a matter: at this point, it is just a fact, and we have to try and make the best out of it. Newest stuff is being moved to Access databases as much as possible, but Excel's visual formatting ability (and ease-of-use for non-techies) still is a high "selling" point for us.

Comment: I am realizing (as you just did) I don't know sh** about SharePoint document library, and it might be different than I first envisionned. A pointer to some n00b-friendly startup info would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-document-library-3b5976dd-65cf-4c9e-bf5a-713c10ca2872

Comment: From your description in the first comment, I would run away.

Comment: A disabled child is a child nonetheless, and deserves as much love and care as the others... ;)
It's indeed quite the monster we have built over time. Some day will get replaced, but not just yet. Still serves its purpose.